# How to know the next free position of array

Tags: c, arrays

In strings, we can know the last of the string thanks to "\0", but how can I know the next free position of an array. Here I put the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int notes[10];
    int i, usuari;

    printf("Put a number");
    scanf("%i", &usuari);

    for (i=0;i<usuari;i++){
        scanf("%i", &notes[i]);
    }
}
```

User will give a number (variable `usuari`). How can I know that the positions next to number, given by user, are free? And how can I print them?

Comment: An array has no "free position". C does not have a string type. It is all convention how arrays are used. Think about it!

Comment: So, how could i print the free positions next to the number where the array ends?

Comment: Define the word `free` ?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. The array ends with `notes[9]` apparently. There is no array past it and there are no "free positions" by default (what would those look like?). You seem to be confused what arrays are. You can learn this from any C book in the corrseponding chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would usually do is to initialize your array to some value that would never be input, for example -1.  So, you can define notes like this:

```
int notes[10] = {-1};
```

Then you can check if notes[i] == -1 before you use it.  But, I'm just guessing what you mean by `unused`.

EDIT:

As pointed out the above only initializes the first element.  You would actually have to initialize notes like this:

```
int notes[10] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,};
```

Or in a loop

Comment: Note that only `notes[0]` would be initialized to `-1`.  One of the more puzzling oversights in the C99 improvements to initializers was the ability to repeat a value some number of times in initializers.  It's doubly odd since Fortran has had it 'for ever' (since Fortran 66, anyway).

Comment: That's right.  you have to initialize it like this:  `int notes[10] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,};`

Answer (score 0):

Either use a terminal value, similar to how strings in C use a terminal value to indicate the end... or store the position of the next value, similar to how your loop knows where to store the next value.

Suppose you move your initialisation of `i` outside of the loop and wrap your user input into a nested loop like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int notes[10];
    int i = 0, usuari;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Put a number");
        scanf("%i", &usuari);

        for (;i<usuari;i++){
            scanf("%i", &notes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

How does the inner-most loop know where to store the next value? The position is stored and incremented for the duration of the variables lifetime, of course... You're storing the length, yeh?